# System.StringException: Invalid id: Id on test classes

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am getting this error in my test class:

> System.StringException: Invalid id: Id

The line throwing the error:

```
testVfPageRef.getParameters().put('quote.Id')
```

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you used  `Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);` ? if yes and still you are getting error, can you post full code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the way, `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put(key,value)` takes key & value pair.

Here is the correct way to use it in test class.

```
//create pageReference
PageReference page = Page.MyVFP;
Test.setCurrentPage(page);

//pass parameter to the page
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',quote.Id);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have single quotes around `quote.Id`, meaning you're trying to populate that literal string value into an Id variable. Remove the quote marks and you should be fine with the reference to an Id-typed field.